# Replace WooCommerce Class

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce has a class "get_shipping_to_display()" in /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/classes/class-wc-order.php, that keeps outputting $36 in my invoices (using the Print Invoice & Packing List plugin) as the value for shipping... regardless of what the shipping out is actually.

I've narrowed it down to that class, as using "get_shipping()" displays the actual shipping price.

I don't want to modify WooCommerce core files (so as not to cause problems with updates later on), so how do I go about replacing that class with my own class in functions.php so I can try and narrow down what is causing the issue... and what would that look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line in the function `get_shipping_to_display()` is:

```
return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_shipping_to_display', $shipping, $this );
```

That means that if you create a filter on `woocommerce_order_shipping_to_display` you can ultimately output whatever you want (though technically contents of that function will still run first). The `$shipping` variable contains the text output you are seeing now and `$this` will have all the properties of the class, including the order `$id`, `$status`, etc which you could use to do whatever lookups/calculations you want.

Comment: Thank you - I must have missed that line so I could hook into it. I'm just still baffled why the WooCommerce default code of $this object generates a shipping price of $36, but the $order object from within the template outputs the correct price... Something for another day, I suppose. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, sounds strange... is it $36 for all products? Maybe something to do with taxes/handling fees?

Comment: I thought so, too, but couldn't find the $36 reference in the backend anywhere... Thanks again!

Comment: Nowadays, the filter has a third parameter: `return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_shipping_to_display', $shipping, $this, $tax_display );`